# How to prevent multiple request in jQuery ajax

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

This is my code, I am try to prevent multiple request in jQuery Ajax;

```
$('#applymentin').submit(function(e)
{
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: url + 'postmenin',
        headers: {
            'mentor_id': window.localStorage.getItem('tmpmenid'),
            'user_id': window.loc
            alStorage.getItem('user_id')
        },

        data: new FormData(this),

        async: false,
        cache: false,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        success: function(data) {
            alert(data.message);

        },
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown,data){
          alert("check your connection");
        }
        });
    });
```

Comment: What do you mean by "multiple request" - do you mean do do not want to run this multiple times concurrently or more than one time (at all), please clarify your desired functionality result.

Comment: when i was post the data via jquery ajax , it should post data in database 5 times...i thing u get ..pls give solution

Comment: `async: false,` is deprecated and should not be used.  As to your clarification attempt, frankly it is now perhaps even less clear.  So you wish to post the data 5 times. (5 total post attempts, 5 consecutive posts, 5 sequential posts (do it 5 times max, tracking every request and prevent a post a 6th time) 5 concurrent posts (post 5 times when requested) ?

Comment: you might right ...but still i have problems in this part ...but this time 6 times inserted ...in DB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you js file as multiple form submit. so you need to bind and unbind form submit . example code

```
 $('#applymentin').unbind('submit').bind('submit',function(e){
e.preventDefault();
  //get the data, coercing to numeric
  let postAttemptCount = $(this).data("postattempt")*1;
  if (postAttemptCount < 5) {
    // increment the count
    $(this).data("postattempt", postAttemptCount + 1);
    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: url + 'postmenin',
      headers: {
        'mentor_id': window.localStorage.getItem('tmpmenid'),
        'user_id': window.loc
        alStorage.getItem('user_id')
      },

      data: new FormData(this),

      async: false,
      cache: false,
      contentType: false,
      processData: false,
      success: function(data) {
        alert(data.message);
      },
      error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown, data) {
        alert("check your connection");
      }
    });
  }
});
```

try this it will work

Answer (score 1):

Take a look to this line: **if(ajax) ajax.abort();**

```
var ajax = false
$(document).on("keyup",'#search-top',function(e){
    $('.header-search-result-inner').html('');
    e.stopImmediatePropagation();
    let keyword = $(this).val();
    if(keyword.length > 2) {
        $('#search-ajax-loader').fadeIn();
        if(ajax) ajax.abort();
        ajax = $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: '/search',
            data: {keyword: keyword},
            dataType: 'html',
            success: function (info) {
                $('.header-search-result').show();
                $('.header-search-result-inner').append(info);
            },
            complete: function () {
                $('#search-ajax-loader').fadeOut();
            }
        });
    }else {
        $('.header-search-result').hide();
        $('#search-ajax-loader').fadeOut();
    }

});
```

Comment: this works for me but still create multiple ajax calls (1 valid and many aborted after each click).

Comment: @Karls yes but I think aborted ajax calls just show in console and not send request to server

Answer (score 0):

There is not a lot information in your question, but I guess that you're worrying about `OPTIONS` request. It's ok to have this request. If I'm right, you could read about `CORS`.

Comment: Hi, This is should be a mobile app slim jquery ajax

Answer (score 0):

I am going to attempt what I THINK your desire is which is to accept posts up to 5 times but not a 6th time.  To do that I would simply use a counter and then reject the attempt after the 5th time.  This should be fairly easy to accomplish.  I am going to use your form and save the data to avoid a global variable.

```js
$('#applymentin').submit(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  //get the data, coercing to numeric
  let postAttemptCount = $(this).data("postattempt")*1;
  if (postAttemptCount < 5) {
    // increment the count
    $(this).data("postattempt", postAttemptCount + 1);
    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: url + 'postmenin',
      headers: {
        'mentor_id': window.localStorage.getItem('tmpmenid'),
        'user_id': window.loc
        alStorage.getItem('user_id')
      },

      data: new FormData(this),

      async: false,
      cache: false,
      contentType: false,
      processData: false,
      success: function(data) {
        alert(data.message);
      },
      error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown, data) {
        alert("check your connection");
      }
    });
  }
});
```

```html
<form id="applymentin" data-postattempt="0">
  my form stuff here
</form>
```